# Seed method not called, Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a `DatabaseInitializer` class

```
public class DatabaseInitializer : CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<DatabaseContext>
{
    protected override void Seed
        (
        DatabaseContext databaseContext
        )
    {
        // Seed the hash methods.
        var defaultHashMethod = new HashMethod
        {
            Description = "Default",
            CreateDate = DateTime.Now
        };

        databaseContext.HashMethod.Add(defaultHashMethod);

        databaseContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

In my DatabaseContext class I set the initializer

```
public DatabaseContext() : base("DatabaseContext")
{
    InitializeDatabase();
}

private void InitializeDatabase()
{
    Database.SetInitializer(new DatabaseInitializer());
    if (!Database.Exists())
    {
        Database.Initialize(true);
    }            
}
```

As far as I can understand the seed method is only invoked once you perform an operation such as a query. My database is created successfully and I'm querying the table, but the seed method is never called.

**Update:**

It seems like the problem is caused because of a class that is `inheriting` from my `DatabaseContext` class, when using this class to perform database operations, the seed method is not called. When using my `DatabaseContext` class, everything works as expected

```
public DbSet<TestEntity> TestEntity { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
}
```

Comment: Did you ever figure out the right way to fix this? I have the same problem.

Comment: @John Shedletsky I added my solution for you as an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only way I could get this to work was to call the seed method myself

Here are the methods for my DatabaseContext class

```
 public DatabaseContext() : base("DatabaseContext")
 {
    InitializeDatabase();
 }

 public DatabaseContext(string connectionString) : base(connectionString)
 {
     Database.Connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
     InitializeDatabase();
 }

 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
 {
     modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
 }
```

Here I changed my InitializeDatabase method from

```
private void InitializeDatabase()
{
    Database.SetInitializer(new DatabaseInitializer());
    if (!Database.Exists())
    {
        Database.Initialize(true);
    }            
}
```

to

```
protected virtual void InitializeDatabase()
{
    if (!Database.Exists())
    {
        Database.Initialize(true);
        new DatabaseInitializer().Seed(this);
    }            
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I did something similar but more hacky, essentially burning out this part of EF and taking control of seeding explicitly. It seems like Update-Database uses a different enough codepath to make life hell when you want to make non-demo apps.

Comment: Thanks @user65439. Would be nice if this fixes it, but the `Seed()` method is `protected`! Because it's an override you can not change the accessor to `public`. And because it's not public you cannot call that method in `DatabaseInitializer` from the `DatabaseContext` class as your code example shows (I get a compile error). I don't get it, what am I missing?

Comment: This solution is the hack and new DatabaseInitializer().Seed(this); will not work because Seed method it is protected. I even do not see any point to call DatabaseInitializer in this context. Just place seed code instead of new DatabaseInitializer().Seed(this);

Comment: This is not the only instance of this - there is another solution here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36024400/migratedatabasetolatestversion-no-running-seed-method - I have no idea why this is happening though, both answers are workarounds to an actual problem I believe

Answer (score 16):

You need to call `Update-Database` from the `Package Manager Console`.

Comment: The problem is when you do this the seed method is not called sometimes.

Comment: for CI, we often don't want to run `Update-Database` from the console. Many people prefer to do it automatically through Web/App.config settings. This way the process is automated and you can easily migrate changes in a new PR to the DB before the PR's tests are run. Otherwise, it defeats the purpose of CI when the builds fail, requiring a dev to go run `update-databse` themselves...

Answer (score 5):

This can happen if your Update-Database command does not run successfully, and this does not necessarily mean that it errors out. There might be changes that EF recognizes as "outstanding" that need to be added to a migration.

Try calling "Add-Migration {migrationNameHere}" and then try "Update-Database" again.

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me. Apparently I had an outstanding migration to add. Once I did that the seed was called.

Comment: Really strange, but this worked for me too. I created a dummy migration, with nothing generated inside it, and when starting the application the Seed was called (after the migrations).

Answer (score 4):

to get `Seed` method to be called when you are **not** using `AutomaticMigration`, you should use `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion` initializer for your code-first database.
like this:

```
Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<YourContext,YourConfiguration>());
```

this way, `Seed` method will be called every time the migration is done successfully.

Comment: This is causing to execute the seed every time a request is sent to db and generates the error 'Sequence contains more than one element' second time onwards, why?

Comment: As the Summary of the (base) Seed method says, you have to be careful and put in checks, so that it can run multiple times. The AddOrUpdate will check for that, depending if have the first parameter correct. (the field(s) that is(are) unique for the check).

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue and the problem was my Context constructor did not use the same name as in my web.config.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Code-First then you can populate the data when the application runs for the first time.

- Create a DbInitializer

  ```
  public class MyDbInitializer : IDatabaseInitializer<MyDbContext>
  {
     public void InitializeDatabase(MyDbContext context)
     {
        if (context.Database.Exists())
        {
          if (!context.Database.CompatibleWithModel(true))
          {
              context.Database.Delete();
          }
        }
        context.Database.Create();

        User myUser = new User()
        {
          Email = "a@b.com",
          Password = "secure-password"
        };
        context.Users.AddOrUpdate<User>(p => p.Email, myUser);
        context.SaveChanges();
     }
  }
  ```
- Register this DbInitializer in your Global.asax.cs  Application_Start method

  ```
  Database.SetInitializer(new My.namespace.MyDbInitializer());
  ```

Comment: what is Global.asax.cs ? I can't find it anywhere

Answer (score 0):

My seed was not being executed either.  However, it was because I added a column to a model that I had no intention of using in my actual database and forgot to use the [NotMapped] annotation.

```
    [NotMapped]
    public string Pair { get; set; }
```

There was no error message relating to this being the cause at all. Just a null reference to my repository obj when I tried to query data that should have been there.