# MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion no running Seed() method

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I'm trying to automatically generate my database if it doesn't exists and run the `Seed()` method to populate the data. In my Database Context constructor I have this:

```
Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MyDBContext, Configuration>());
```

This works great, my database is automatically created with all the tables as I want, but it seems like the `Seed()` method is not being called, my database is empty. This is my class:

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<Context.MyDBContext>
{

    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
    }

    protected override void Seed(Context.MyDBContext context)
    {
        context.Users.AddOrUpdate(
            new Entities.User() { Email = "default@default.com", Password = "", Language = "en", CreatedDate = DateTime.Now }
        );

        base.Seed(context);
    }
}
```

When I run `Update-Database` in the `Nuget` console the data is populated after database creation, but with `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion` the `Seed()` method is not called.

What can be happening? I tried manually running migrations as taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10848746/using-entity-framework-code-first-migrations-in-production%20%22%22):

```
var configuration = new MyDbContextConfiguration();
configuration.TargetDatabase = new DbConnectionInfo(
    database.ConnectionString, database.ProviderName);

var migrator = new DbMigrator(configuration);
migrator.Update();
```

But also doesn't work.

---

**EDIT:**

Ok, after some more testing I found that the `Seed()` method runs but only when the database already exists, that is, on the first run when the database is created for the first time the `Seed()` method is not executed, but when I run my app the second time `Seed()` get's executed. I also had to add `context.SaveChanges()` in order for it to work (thanks to @DavidG in the comments):

```
protected override void Seed(Context.MyDBContext context)
    {
        context.Users.AddOrUpdate(
            new Entities.User() { Email = "default@default.com", Password = "", Language = "en", CreatedDate = DateTime.Now }
        );

        context.SaveChanges();
        base.Seed(context);
    }
```

So maybe I can manually call `Seed()` inside `Configuration()` and do some checking to avoid adding duplicating data or modifying data that already exists.

Comment: Doesn't work is not enough. Did you try to step into with a debugger? Is the Seed method being called? If it is, the problem might be trying to initialize an user that way. Use UserManager instead

Comment: Can you throw an exception in the `Seed` method to verify that the seed method was not run at all (and not that simply the user wasn't inserted into the database?).

Comment: You are not calling `context.SaveChanges();` after you add your users.

Comment: @DavidG save changes is not necessary in `Seed()`. Probably the base.Seed() is calling it.

Comment: @RoyalBg Yes, you may be right there. I always explicitly call `SaveChanges` so I can't remember the default behaviour! Perhaps we an see the context class too?

Comment: @Royal Bg Yes, I used the debugger and it's not being called. Will update the question with the context class.

Comment: Did you try also to manually rund from powershell console `Update-Database`? Once I hit a rare scenario I need to register the initializer in the app.config too

Comment: @RoyalBg With the nugget console, running Update-Database creates the database and the data is populated as it should.

Comment: This is the expected behavior btw. If you want anytime you start the application to create db and seed, you have to ensure you manually call the `Seed` method (e.g. in the config constructor). Only `Update-Database` ensures calling the seed automatically. If you have a build script (recipe), add `Update-Database` to the batch.

Comment: @RoyalBg No, I want the database to be created when it doesn't exists and after new migrations are executed the Seed() method should be executed too

Comment: I'm out of ideas, but you can still try to add the initializer to the xml - http://www.asp.net/media/4367421/mig.png

Comment: You know there is another Seed() method on your initializer that only runs when the database is created as opposed to migration seed that runs with every update-database. I use the initializer seed during early development then switch to migrations when app is out in other enviroments. http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2013/05/28/database-initializer-and-migrations-seed-methods/

Comment: @SteveGreene in this case that's incorrect, as he is using the MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion initializer which has no Seed() method available for override.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I ended up with this `Configuration` class:

```
public class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<Context.MyDBContext>
    {
        private readonly bool _pendingMigrations;

        public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;

            // Check if there are migrations pending to run, this can happen if database doesn't exists or if there was any
            //  change in the schema
            var migrator = new DbMigrator(this);
            _pendingMigrations = migrator.GetPendingMigrations().Any();

            // If there are pending migrations run migrator.Update() to create/update the database then run the Seed() method to populate
            //  the data if necessary
            if (_pendingMigrations)
            {
                migrator.Update();
                Seed(new Context.MyDBContext());
            }
        }

        protected override void Seed(Context.MyDBContext context)
        {
            // Microsoft comment says "This method will be called after migrating to the latest version."
            // However my testing shows that it is called every time the software starts

            // Run whatever you like here

            // Apply changes to database
            context.SaveChanges();
            base.Seed(context);
        }
    }
```

So on this way the `Seed()` method is called when the database is created and also when there are pending migrations.

This is my `MyDBContext` class:

```
public class MyDBContext: DbContext
{
    public MyDBContext() : base(AppSettings.DBConnectionString)
    {
    }

    public static MyDBContext Create()
    {
        return new MyDBContext();
    }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Entries> Entries { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I have same problem, but your solution creates infinite loop for me. To be specific this part `Seed(new Context.MyDBContext());` It create new `DbContext` which creates new `Configuratio` which creates new `DbContext` and so on until StackOverflow exception

Comment: See the example `MyDBContext` class I added to the answer. For me it's working perfectly in a production environment with no problems at all.

Comment: Where `Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MyDBContext, Configuration>());` should now be called - it is missing in `MyDbContext` constructor?

Comment: `Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MyDBContext, Configuration>());` is called on your application startup so it will check the if the database exists and apply any pending migrations

Comment: Okay, I found the problem. Very nice solution by the way.

Comment: `_pendingMigrations = migrator.GetPendingMigrations().Any();` crashes Visual Studio 2017 when calling `Add-Migration`. Verified on two different dev machines. Why?